# Django next with query parameters

Tags: python, django, redirect

My website has a list of pages that are under /record and available only with query parameters of type and id. Like so:

> /record?type=poem&id=175

I am using the django next redirect to go from the login page to the previous page. I initially used `href="{% url 'auth:login' %}?next={{ request.path }}"` to redirect, but it didn't take the query parameters (i.e type and id). This takes the user to

> /login/?next=/record

I then used `href="'{% url 'auth:login' %}?next={{ request.path }}'+window.location.search"`. However, this doesn't work as well. This takes the user to

> /login/?next=/record?type=poem&id=175

but it finally redirects to

> /record

How do I redirect using next along with query parameters? Is this behavior not possible?

Comment: Out of what I recall, could you try: `request.get_full_path()` ?

Comment: "request.get_full_path"* you mean. However, doing that works the same as using widow.location.search. It first takes me to `/login/?next=/record?type=poem&id=171` but then finally takes me to `/record` as if ignoring the query parameters.

Comment: This `?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}` should be the ideal case. Could you showcase the view you have written and also your settings.py `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ?

Comment: It's working. That's the reason it's taking me to `/login/?next=/record?type=poem&id=171` in the first place. But after I am logged in, it simply redirects to `/record` ignoring the query parameters.
I do have `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Using `urlencode`, `/login/?next=/record?type=poem&id=171` just changes to `/login/?next=/record%3Ftype%3Dpoem%26id%3D170`. But in the end both redirect to `/record`

Comment: Are you saying, its still not working? If its still not working, then could you update your question with the `view`, `form template` and settings.py `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ? Because you should have been getting the query string in the view.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape special characters in the URL, namely '?', '&' and '='.
While there is [django.utils.encoding.escape_uri_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.escape_uri_path), it doesn't escape the ampersand (&), which is a problem because it will be interpreted as the end of the `next` parameter and the beginning of another.

Instead, you can use [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
from urllib.parse import quote
current_url_escaped = quote(request.get_full_path())
```

and in the template:

```
href="{% url 'auth:login' %}?next={{ current_url_escaped }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can **use [`HttpRequest.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path)** method along with [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) template filter to get the current url along with the query string.

> [`HttpRequest.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path)
>   Returns the path, plus an appended query string, if applicable.

```
href="{% url 'auth:login' %}?next={{request.get_full_path|urlencode}}
```

Comment: Doing that works the same as using widow.location.search. It first takes me to
`/login/?next=/record?type=poem&id=171`
but then finally takes me to `/record` as if ignoring the query parameters.

Comment: Please check whether in your login view, you are preserving parameters or not when redirecting to `next` url.

Comment: What do you mean by preserving parameters? How exactly would I do that?

Comment: When redirecting to `next` url, you should also add the url parameters to the `next` url so that it gets passed to `/record` url.